# Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *" doesn't support the In-App Purchase capability

Tags: swift, xcode, flutter, io, flutter-test

I am trying to add an in-app purchase to iOS, I am getting an error. If I remove the in-app purchase from capability. Then I get no errors. How can I solve this?
And the identifier I am using is mine. In the first error, I am getting that the identifier is not available.

[image]

Comment: Check `developer.apple.com` in profiles if your provisioning profile has the `in-App Purcharse` capility, if it doesn't have what seems to be the case then go to `Identifiers` and select your identifier and add the `in-App Purcharse` finally use the new provisioning profile. Probably the other way to solve this, but this is how I solved this problem.

Comment: Perfect, I'll generate an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `developer.apple.com` in profiles if your provisioning profile has the `in-App Purcharse` capility, if it doesn't have what seems to be the case then go to `Identifiers` and select your identifier and add the `in-App Purcharse` finally use the new provisioning profile. Probably the other way to solve this, but this is how I solved this problem.